# Sending data over usb/RS232 converter using java

Tags: java, c++, serial-port, usb, cross-platform

I want to send data over a usb port where it's pluged in a converter from USB to RS232 using a java application.
After one day searching I found 3 solution :

1.use an api : which is hard cause every api have it's limitation or not updated or died years ago or not cross platform and that's what i need.

2.identify the usb connector as a RS232 connector by an OS : well this I want to know more about cause it seems a better solution.

3.make my own usb/java api : I don't even know where to start ! .

update 1 : 
 I'm currently using the library JSSC to control the flux on a serial Port.

update 2 :

well while I'm at it, if there's a solution using C++ and if there is, how to make C++ code work under a java Application.

So if there's any help with this would be welcome and sorry for making it too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The only way to interact with the USB/RS232 device is via the OS and its representation of a COM port. You cannot control the USB device directly.
2. Java does not provide a means to control a COM/RS232/serial port off the shelf.
3. This functionality can be added to Java by leveraging native code (e.g. in C or C++) and the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).
4. This has been done before, see for example: [Stable alternative to RXTX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317576/stable-alternative-to-rxtx)

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear here, is there a way to send/recieve data over usb/RS232 ? and when I connect the materiel(Converter usb/RS232) can the OS make it known as a serial port and then i'll use the JSSC(Cause i'm already using it to send data over a COM port and for me it's better than RXTX).

Comment: The USB device will come with a driver for the OS and when installed will look like any other ordinary COM port to applications. So, if you have a USB<->RS232 converter and you properly installed it, any software that can use a COM port can use the 'USB COM port' too, including RXTX or any other library.

Comment: thanks this is valuable i didn't know that as I still didn't get the device.