# Why do I keep Getting null Pointer Exception in Serial port communication Program

Tags: java, serial-port

Okay so I have a couple of problems here first I keep getting a nullPointerException when trying to connect to com port 3, I have tried this several different ways, first by just selecting the port and going after it secondly by searching for the port and trying it. The second time around I kept getting this 32 bit 64 bit mismatch exception for my RXTX lib so I fixed that and then came up with this error

```
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
       Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
       native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Failed to open COM3(java.lang.NullPointerException)
Failed to open COM3(java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

Which I can't seem to figure out because I got both of them from the same place. However My issue still lies with the Null Pointer Exception so here is a view of my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SPMRV2 extends MyFrame{
UserSerialV2 communicator = null;

//combo Box for Com port selection
public JComboBox comBox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5"});
private JButton selectBtn = new JButton("Select");

//Buttons or the starting and stopping of the program Start will initialize the   program stop will close the port for communication
private JButton startBtn = new JButton("Connect");
private JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Disconnect");

    //message Area for log
    private JTextArea logDisplay = new JTextArea(" ", 200, 45);
    private JTextField newTextFile = new JTextField();
    private JLabel fileLabel = new JLabel("Please Enter The File You Wish To Log To: \n");

public SPMRV2(){
    initComponents();
    createObjects();

}

public void createObjects(){
    communicator = new UserSerialV2();
}

public void initComponents(){
    //set Button Listeners
    ButtonListener selected = new ButtonListener();
    startBtn.addActionListener(selected);
    stopBtn.addActionListener(selected);
    selectBtn.addActionListener(selected);

    JPanel comSelect = new JPanel();
        comSelect.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        comSelect.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Select Your Com Port"));
        comSelect.add(comBox);
        comSelect.add(fileLabel);
        comSelect.add(newTextFile);
        comSelect.add(selectBtn);

    JPanel action = new JPanel();
        action.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        action.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Start/Stop console"));
        action.add(startBtn);
        action.add(stopBtn);

    JPanel leftContainer = new JPanel();
        leftContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftContainer.add(comSelect, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        leftContainer.add(action, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel rightContainer = new JPanel();
        rightContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        rightContainer.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Members Logged"));
        rightContainer.add(logDisplay);

    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        wrapper.add(leftContainer, BorderLayout.WEST);
        wrapper.add(rightContainer, BorderLayout.EAST);

    add(wrapper);

}   

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          new SPMRV2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }

    //Start/Stop/Select/Quit Button Listener Class
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        String userFile = "";
        String newComPort = "";
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(e.getSource() == selectBtn){
                    comBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
                            }

                    });
                        newComPort = (String)comBox.getSelectedItem();
                        userFile = newTextFile.getText();
                           communicator.searchForPorts(newComPort);
                           logDisplay.append(communicator.searchForPorts(newComPort));
                        logDisplay.append("You are going to     be communicating through Comm Port: " + newComPort + "\n");
                        logDisplay.append("And you will be     Logging info to text File: " + userFile + "\n");
        }

        if(e.getSource() == startBtn){
             communicator.initiate(newComPort);
                if (communicator.getConnected() == true){
                    if (communicator.readerStream() == true){
                        communicator.startListener();
                        communicator.logging(userFile);
                    }
                }

        }else if(e.getSource() == stopBtn){
            communicator.disconnect();
            }


    }

    }


}
```

this is the gui setup that I am using and the following is my serial program

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

public class UserSerialV2 extends SPMR implements SerialPortEventListener{
//create string to store exception readout in
String excepText = "";
public boolean bConnected = false;

/*
Creates a file and additional info for serial logging storage
*/
public static String file = "";
public static String data = "";
public static final java.util.Date LOG_DATE = new java.util.Date();

//for containing the ports that will be found
private Enumeration serialPorts = null;
//map the port names to CommPortIdentifiers
private HashMap portMap = new HashMap();

//this is the object that contains the opened port
private CommPortIdentifier selectedPortIdentifier = null;
private SerialPort serialPort = null;

//input and output streams for sending and receiving data
public InputStream input = null;
private OutputStream output = null;

//the timeout value for connecting with the port
final static int TIMEOUT = 5000;

//some ascii values for for certain things
final static int SPACE_ASCII = 32;
final static int DASH_ASCII = 45;
final static int NEW_LINE_ASCII = 10;

    public UserSerialV2(){

    }

    public String searchForPorts(String userComm){
    serialPorts = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (serialPorts.hasMoreElements()){
        CommPortIdentifier currentPort = (CommPortIdentifier)serialPorts.nextElement();

        //get only serial ports
        if (currentPort.getName() == userComm){             
            portMap.put(currentPort.getName(), currentPort);
                data = "Found Com Port 3";

        }
    }
    return data;
 }

public void initiate(String comPort){
        String selectedPort = comPort;
    selectedPortIdentifier = (CommPortIdentifier)portMap.get(selectedPort);

    CommPort commPort = null;

    try{
        //the method below returns an object of type CommPort
        commPort = selectedPortIdentifier.open("User Serial APP", TIMEOUT);
        //the CommPort object can be casted to a SerialPort object
        serialPort = (SerialPort)commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);

            setConnected(true);
        //logging
        data = selectedPort + " opened successfully.";

        // //CODE ON SETTING BAUD RATE ETC OMITTED
             // try {
                // serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            // SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            // SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            // SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        // } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e){
            // System.out.println(e);
        // }//end try catch block

    }
    catch (PortInUseException e){
        excepText = selectedPort + " is in use. (" + e.toString() + ")";
            System.out.println(excepText);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        excepText = "Failed to open " + selectedPort + "(" + e.toString() + ")";
            System.out.println(excepText);
    }
}

    //method to collect input from the port
public boolean readerStream() {
    //boolean value variable for input stream
        boolean success = false;
        try{
            input = serialPort.getInputStream();
        success = true;
        return success;
    }catch(IOException e){
        excepText = "I/O Streams Failed To Open" + "(" + e.toString() +         ")";
        System.out.println(excepText);
        return success;
    }
}//end readerStream

//method to start listener when user connects to port
public void startListener(){
    try{
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    }catch(TooManyListenersException e){
        excepText = "Too many listeners" + "(" + e.toString() + ")";
        System.out.println(excepText);
    }   
}

//Method to disconnect from the serial port when the user is finished with logging 
public void disconnect(){
    try{
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
        input.close();
        data = "Disconnected";
        setConnected(false);
    }catch(Exception e){
        excepText = "(" + e.toString() + ")";
        System.out.println("Disconnect Problem " + excepText);
    }
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
    if (event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){
        try{
              byte singleData = (byte)input.read();

            if (singleData != NEW_LINE_ASCII){
                this.data = new String(new byte[] {singleData});
            }
            else
            {
                this.data = "\n";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            excepText = "(" + e.toString() + ")";
            System.out.println("Serial Event Problem " + excepText);
        }
    }
}

final public boolean getConnected()
{
    return bConnected;
}

public void setConnected(boolean bConnected)
{
    this.bConnected = bConnected;
}

public String logging(String file){
    UserLogFile log = new UserLogFile();
                    log.openFile(file);
                    log.addLog(data + LOG_DATE);
                    log.closeFile();
    return data;
}
```

}

I have asked this question before but can't seem to get any responses, any body got any ideas as to what could be causing the problem???

Thanks,

oh and userlogFile is mentioned in the code as well it was just a simple writing class I was using to pass information to a text file of the users that Logged in.

Comment: Dumb question here... Have you checked if the COM3 port is enable on your computer?

Comment: Many have had trouble with [RXTX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12317617/398460). Have you tried [jSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/)?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` is your friend - you should call it in `catch (Exception e)` block to see where exactly did it break. And get the RXTX source code and locate the issue.