# Tomcat on raspberry pi couldnt initialize gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, raspberry-pi, rxtx

I have Oracle's Java JDK 8 and Tomcat 8 installed on Raspberry PI.

I have a standalone and a web application, both with the same functionaties (open serial communication). Both are running on my macbook.

The problem is:
The standalone application runs well on raspbian when I give the CLASSPATH with RXTXcomm.jar, like `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar:. -jar myapp.jar`

But the web application doesn't run. I put the war file is Tomcat's webapps directory. When I try to go to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/`, I get the message:

**HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier**

What would cause it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying a compatible version of RXTXcomm.jar into your tomcat/lib directory. All jars in Tomcat/lib are available on the classpath when running webapps.

Comment: BTW, since you are developing serial port communications on RasPi, this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317576/stable-alternative-to-rxtx