# Trying to set lib path in code for RXTX in java on Pi

Tags: java, rxtx, lib

Have Java program running on Windows and Raspberry Pi. When running the program on Pi, I need to use `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni`

> when I run the jar so the `RXTX libs can be found`. I want to do it in
>   code with  `System.setProperty()`, but it doesn't work.

Any known issues with `setProperty()` on Pi?

Verified so files on Pi are in `/usr/lib/jni`. Print out shows path is being sent to `setProperty()` as expected.

```
    if (doPi == true)
        s = "/usr/lib/jni"; // Pi so files
    else
        s = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_181\\bin"; // Win dll files

    System.setProperty("java.library.path", s);
    System.out.println("Java lib path " + s);
```

I expected the `setProperty()` code would allow me to not need

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

When running the jar file.

> But without it, I get an error that the `RXTX lib files are not found`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the path to the RXTX lib files need to be set **before starting the application**. So setting it using the `System.setProperty()` method is probably working, but it sets the property after the programm started, and therefore after the property was read.

I'm using the RXTX lib on RaspberryPi for quite a while now and I haven't found a way to start this applications without the command line parameters. The easiest way to start the application probably is a small *bash script*.

Another way would be to not use RXTX (which is quite old and not realy recommendable), but use an alternative like described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317576/stable-alternative-to-rxtx).

Comment: Found relevant info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419039/is-djava-library-path-equivalent-to-system-setpropertyjava-library-path  luyifan answer worked for me.